# How is this url formed with '"+img_url+"'?

Tags: javascript, html, image, url, character

Below is part of a simple code used to show the location in a Google Map (using a static image).

No error here, I just wanna an explanation of the code `<img src='+img_url+'>`

I can't figure out how the url of the `<img>` `src` is made up.

I thought `img_url` is intact but what is the use of `+` here?

And why does it need `'"` here?

```
function showPosition(position) {
    var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
    var img_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
    +latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU";
    document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = "<img src='"+img_url+"'>";
}
```

Comment: `+` in the context of strings is a concatenation operator. But without `'"` it would mean nothing as that whole bit is being treated as a single string and not js code doing concatenation

Comment: because string concatenation.... " is the start and looks for the next " to be closed.

Comment: Is there an error or are you just asking for an explanation?

Comment: No error here. Just wanna an explanation.  @Jay A. Little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` as a string operator concatenates (adds) strings together.

example:
`var name = "David"` and `var string = "Hello "+name`
`string` will print as `"Hello David"`

So I created a variable that held a string, then added that variable to another string. (concatenation)

The HTML image tag needs to end up like this: `<img src='www.example.com/image.jpg'>`
(Notice the single quotes, could be double, but in your example it uses single)

Here the JavaScript is building the image url to insert into the `src` attribute.

`var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;`
This takes two variables (lat and long) and puts them into one string and inserts a comma in between them. This one string becomes its own variable called `latlon`.

`var img_url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
    +latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU";`
This takes that new `latlon` variable and inserts it into the googleapis url to complete the url and saves this complete url as `img_url`.

`document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = "<img src='"+img_url+"'>";`
And finally this line finds the element with the id "mapholder" and changes its content to be `<img src=''>` and at the same time, inserts the complete url inside the `src` single quotes.

So now to explain this line: `"<img src='"+img_url+"'>"`

the first `"` opens the string and starts the image tag with `<img src='`, at which point we need to insert the complete url.
So then close the string with a second `"` then use `+` to add the variable `img_url`,
but the image tag isn't finished so use another `+` to add something else after the url, which is another string so open another string with `"` and finish the image tag with `'>` and finally close the string with one last `"`.